# How to disable RadComboxBox only when its source is Empty and display a tooltip message

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have to add a RadComboBox inside a GridViewDataColumn. This combo box has to be populated with a List. I have to make a condition that if the List is empty then this combo box should be disabled and a tooltip message has to be shown that "No Settings available".

Below is my code in xaml file:

```
<telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"
                                                            Width="Auto"
                                                            Header="Decrypt" x:Name="colDecrypt">
    <telerikGrid:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerikGridView:GridViewCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerikGridView:GridViewCell">
                        <Border>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cbxDecrypt" Margin="5,1,5,1" Width="Auto"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Parameter}, Path=EquivalenceNames}"
                                            SelectionChanged="cbxDecrypt_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEquivalence}"
                                            ToolTipService.ToolTip="No Decrypt Settings available"
                                            />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </telerikGrid:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>
</telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a simple example:
we will use ObservableCollection as DataContext:

```
DataContext = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

By default tooltip doesn't showing on Disabled controls, so we need to use ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled property.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="No Decrypt Settings available"/>
                </DataTrigger>    
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

If you use Noxaml version of telerik libraries, then you need some fix like:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadComboBoxStyle}">
    <!--...-->
</Style>
```

Comment: I am using it in my Silver light application. When I am using ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled or Style.Triggers, it is giving an error that "The attachable property 'ShowOnDisabled' was not found in the Type ToolTipService". Is there any specific reason for that? Sorry but I am new to it.

Comment: Yes, in Silverlight we can't use such property. But we have solution - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/123961/ToolTip-for-Disabled-Element-in-Silverlight

Comment: Yes, it works. Can you please suggest how can I disable an item if its source is empty?

Comment: Empty content of source? Some DataTrigger with apropriate condition.

Comment: Yes, but Data Trigger also is not supported by Silver light application. Anyways thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: For replacement of DataTrigger you can read here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3529508/1979354

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96643/discussion-between-spawn-and-shivam-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

I found below links very useful which gives an easy solution to my problem:

1. For first issue to disable an item if List is empty, a very easy solution is provided here:

[ComboBox IsEnabled Binding Question in Silverlight Xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301034/combobox-isenabled-binding-question-in-silverlight-xaml)

2. For second issue to show a tooltip message, a very good solution is provided here:
   http://dotplusnet.blogspot.in/2010/09/workaround-for-showing-tooltip-for.html

Using Border Background="Transparent" works like a charm to resolve this issue.